# How to make Android App Bundles exclude proguard.map in build?

Tags: android, proguard

When i build .aab file. I want to exclude BUNDLE-METADATA\com.android.tools.build.obfuscation\proguard.map in build.
Any option can do this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Rename .aab to .rar/.zip.
2. Open as archive
3. Delete the folder
4. Rename .aab
   You do not need to re-sign the application

Answer (score -2):

This makes no sense at all, because the symbols cannot be mapped then, eg. in case of a crash. The assumption, that only because you upload it, someone else would download it, is a slippery slope. Just try to manually delete it from the archive once and then try to upload it; it should get rejected.

Comment: I knew this mapping for crash tracelog, but i don't want it, i can map it myself.

Comment: I don't want Google to knew anything metadata from my app at all.

Comment: This file adds 3MB to my bundle which make me reach my 15MB limit for my instant app, I suppose Crashlytics already upload this file for me, so, it is not required to be packed with my AAB file. 
@Rian-Piece did you find any solution for this?